# Difference in absolute positioning of Text in iText5 and iText7

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am trying to migrate from `iText5` to `iText7`, but there has been an issue with absolute positioning of texts. It seems that there's a quite a bit of offset in the relative positions of same texts even after giving exact same measurements to iText5 and iText7.

Here is the code that shows the problem:

```
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Font;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //using iText7
            var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var fileName = "iText7.pdf";
            var workingName = "iText5.pdf";
            var finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
            var WorkingFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, workingName);


            var pdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(finalPath);
            var pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            var doc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdfDoc, new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(620.986F, 813.543F));

            var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("HELVETICA", BaseFont.CP1252, false);


            doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

            doc.PutText(new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("TESTLINE").SetFont(font), ConvertCoords(189, 10));
            doc.Flush();
            doc.Close();

            //using iText5
            using (var FS = new FileStream(WorkingFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (var Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(620.986F, 813.543F), 0, 0, 0, 0))
                {
                    using (var Writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS))
                    {
                        Doc.Open();
                        Doc.NewPage();
                        var pcb = Writer.DirectContent;
                        pcb.BeginText();

                        //var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
                        var fontbold = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);                        

                        pcb.SetFontAndSize(fontbold, 12);
                        pcb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "TESTLINE", (float)ConvertCoords(189, 10).GetX(), (float)ConvertCoords(189, 10).GetY(), 0);

                        pcb.EndText();
                        Writer.Flush();
                        Doc.Close();
                    }

                }
            }



        }

        private static void PutText(this iText.Layout.Document doc, iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph text, Point coords,
                                    iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment horizontalalign = iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.LEFT,
                                    iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment verticalalign = iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment.TOP)
        {

            doc.ShowTextAligned(text, (float)coords.GetX(), (float)coords.GetY(), horizontalalign, verticalalign);
        }

        //Converts mm to Point
        private static Point ConvertCoords(float a, float b)
        {
            return new Point(a * 2.834265, (287 - b) * 2.834645669291);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using C#. Could anyone be kind enough to solve this problem? Otherwise, I'd have to undertake a Herculean task to remeasure all the forms.

EDIT:

As per the suggestion, I corrected the oversight of using two different page sizes. I have edited my code above. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: *"exact same measurements"* - you already start with documents with different page sizes... and there are other alignment differences, too.

Comment: If you are comparing differences in absolute positioning, please use an example that tries to put the same text at the same position, as mkl pointed out, you're already using different page sizes. I also have no idea where the method `Document#PutText` comes from, it's not present in the latest build of 7

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck `PutText()` is a static method mentioned in the code I provided.

Comment: @SabyasachiMukherjee my bad, I glanced over it when reading through the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unfortunately I can only explain the cause of the behavior but don't know a non-lowlevel iText 7 API method to solve it.*

Aside from a small difference between the document sizes (`620.986F x 813.543F` for your iText 5 code, `619.2f x 813.6f` for your iText 7 code) the main cause for differences in the positioning is that

- for your iText 5 code the **y** coordinate of the `PdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned` call denotes the ***base line* of the text** while
- for your iText 7 code the **y** coordinate of your `PutText` method call by default denotes ***the top* of the text** (as you assign the value `iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment.TOP` as default).

When porting from iText 5 to iText 7 the obvious solution to look for would be a base line vertical alignment.

As far as I can see, though, iText 7 currently unfortunately only knows the following vertical alignment values

```
public enum VerticalAlignment {
    TOP,
    MIDDLE,
    BOTTOM
}
```

*([VerticalAlignment.cs](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.layout/itext/layout/properties/VerticalAlignment.cs))*

As the base line usually is somewhere between the middle and the bottom but hardly ever coincides with either one, the vertical alignment you are looking for is missing.

Thus, you effectively have to calculate the ascender of your text line just like the iText 7 `TextRenderer` class does, and add that to the **y** coordinate parameter of the `TOP` aligned text. Or write a new text renderer which does *not* offset by the ascender to start with.

Comment: Thank you. I will write a script to add a little offset to all the y-coordinates. Since the offset is constant, it won't be much of a problem, I hope.

Comment: @SabyasachiMukherjee It's constant for the same font and font size. If your forms are not to playful concerning these properties, that solution indeed may work for you. It would still be an interesting feature for iText 7 to add a vertical alignment *base line*...